# C++ increment operator and sum

Tags: c++, increment, operator-keyword

Hey I have a problem,

The question is as follows in my book (not homework lol):

Give the value of the variables and continue with the recent gotten value:

```
int i,j,k;
i=j=2;
k=3;
```

Expression

1) **i = ++j + ++k**

```
Result after expression:
int i=3 (or 7?);
int j= 3;
int k=4;
```

2) (following the values after first exercise)-> **i = ++j + k++**

```
Result after expression:
int i=3 (or also 8, since k is +1 after the expression?)
int j= 4;
int k=5;
```

3) (following the values from #2) -> **i = j++ + ++k**

```
Result after expression
int i=3 (or also 10? since j is +1 after the expression, so we take value from #2 ?)
int j=5;
int k=6;
```

I am very confused since I can not check it on my code editor program, it could be easier if i was named: int answer; i guess but how do I check if what i got for int i is true?

Hopefully someone can help me!

Cheers

Comment: Did you try to do it and see the output? Or did you get error?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I tried but it gives error, something about 'operator=' is not allowed.

Comment: Put it in a source-file, add some boiler-plate code and basic print-statements, run it. Was that so impossible? We can assure you the given code is well-behaved.

Comment: I'm asking if the way I'm doing it, is correct, since I have 2 solutions for int i. I cannot confirm if I got the answer or not.

Comment: #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

   int i,j,k;
   i=j=2;
   k=3;

    cout << i = ++j + ++k;
    return 0;
}

not running

Comment: Nearly there: Put the calculation before the output statement, and output all three variables: `cout << i << j << k;` BTW: Your alternative answers are good, though the comments are off.

Comment: Ahhhhhh!!! Sequence Points!!! Search StackOverflow for more information about "sequence points".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Sequencing is ok here, the code in the question has well-defined behavior.

Comment: Thank you vermuch Deduplicator!!!!!! Saved my 2 hours of misery haha!!

Comment: @DavidPostill: Please try to do more substantive edits. Yes, I know most of your edits were approved, but we have a robo-reviewer problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I identified

> how do I check if what i got for int i is true?

as being your main question?

You check it by writing a short C program that calculates the values (which is simple copy-pasting) and prints them on the console, i.e. with

```
printf("After assignment: i=%i j=%i k=%i\n", i, j, k);
```

(don't forget to `#include <stdio>`)

Then you simply compile and run it and check its console output.